# Selenium webdriver: finding all elements with similar id

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I have this xpath: `//*[@id="someId::button"]`

Pressing it shows a dropdown list of values.

Now, I know all the elements in the list have an id like this :

```
//*[@id="someId--popup::popupItemINDEX"]
```

, where INDEX is a number from 1 to whatever the number of options are.

I also know the value which I must click.

One question would be: since I will always know the id of the button which generates the dropdown, can I get all the elements in the dropdown with a **reusable** method? (I need to interact with more than one dropdown)

The way I thought about it is:
get the root of the initial ID, as in:

```
//*[@id="someId
```

then add the rest : `--popup::popupItem`. I also need to add the index and I thought I could use a try block (in order to get though the exceptions when I give a bigger than expected index) like this:

```
 for(int index=1;index<someBiggerThanExpectedNumber;index++){
     try{
         WebElement aux= driver.findElement(By.xpath(builtString+index+"\"]"));
         if(aux.getText().equals(myDesiredValue))
             aux.click();
     }catch(Exception e){}
 }
```

Note that I am using the webdriver api and java.

***I would like to know if this would work and if there is an easier way of doing this, given the initial information I have.***

EDIT: The way I suggested works, but for an easier solution, the accepted answer should be seen

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, try to select more elements by one query, if possible. Searching for many elements one-by-one will get seriously slow.

If I understand your needs well, a good way to do this would be using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("someId::button")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'someId--popup::popupItem') " +
    "and text()='" + myDesiredValue + "']"))
    .click();
```

For more information about XPath, see [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). It's surprisingly a very good read if you can skip the crap!

That finds and clicks an element with text equal to you desired value which contains "someId--popup::popupItem" in its ID.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'someId--popup::popupItem')]"));
```

That finds all just all elements that contain "someId--popup::popupItem" in their ID. You can then traverse the list and look for your desired element.

Did you know you can call `findElement()` on a `WebElement` to search just it's children?
 - `driver.findElement(By.id("someId")).findElements(By.className("clickable"))`

Without a peek on the underlying HTML, I guess I can't offer the best approach, but I have some in my head.

Comment: trying to find all elements won't work, as the list is generated ad-hoc, besides the id part, all other attributes have different values all the time, even if the values are the same. I first need to press the dropdown button to be able to access/see the elements. Thanks for the input on finding children of elements!

Comment: I still can't really see the problem. Click the dropdown button, then find all shown elements?

Comment: `//*[contains(@id, 'someId--popup::popupItem') and text()='myDesiredValue']` selects the one element which ID contains "someId--popup::popupItem" and which text value equals your desired value. ... after the dropdown button was clicked, of course.

Comment: (also, I edited the answer, because the `ElementNotVisibleException` part wasn't really needed and I didn't realize it until now)

Comment: I'm trying the contains and text() part, but it cannot find anything.

Comment: It CAN find the item if I use only the text() part. So that's the easiest way so far. Also, I've managed to implement it in both ways (the one I initially wanted to do, which is messy, and using your input). Thanks for the help! I have to accept your answer, since it offered the solution and more.

Comment: Try it in Firefox + Firebug + Firefinder (any other similar tool) first. If that works, than it's probably just a usual "can't find an element before it showed up" problem - which is treatable by [Implicit/Explicit wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

Comment: I am using firefox and firebug to find the xpaths, but I have to use chrome for the actual implementation. On a side note, that wait will come in handy :)

Comment: Glad I could help! The Firefinder addon is good for _searching_ by xpath. I use it when some xpath doesn't behave the way it should. And the (lack of) wait is the most common cause of problems here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [JavascriptExecutor](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)?

If you are willing to write a little JavaScript then this would be straightforward than in java (I think)

All you will need to do is have some JavaScript crawl through the DOM subtree, and return a list of DOM elements matching your criteria. WebDriver will then happily marshall this as `List<WebElement>` in the java world.

Comment: at this point in time, the project relies heavily on many other auxiliary classes/methods.

Answer (score 1):

The Safer Method to use here is

```
int size=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='someId::button']")).size();

Start using Index Now

String builtString="//*[@id='someId::button'][";

for(int index=1;index<=size();index++)
{

try
{

   WebElement aux= driver.findElement(By.xpath(builtString+index+"\"]"));

   if(aux.getText().equals(myDesiredValue))
             aux.click();

}
catch(Exception e){}

}
```

Please Let me know is the above funda is working or not.

Comment: It doesn't look to me like you understood the question.